# Is it a bad idea to have the IP of my network switches on another subnet to the main network?

Tags: networking

Meaning that I'd have to change my subnet in order to access them?

The main network would flow through them like normal on the main network's subnet, but to access the managed switch's interface I'd have to change my subnet to that of which the switches are running?

Is this bad practice?

Comment: To have a separate subnet (and a separate VLAN if used) for commutators administration is a best practice. *I'd have to change my subnet in order to access them?* You may add secondary address to your NIC settings (if static). Or you may use a separate NIC for this purposes (the best way).

Comment: @Akina  The definition of commutator -  "A commutator is a rotary electrical switch in certain types of electric motors".   So what do you mean by " for commutators administration" ?

Comment: My native language is Russian. And in IT branch the terms "switch" and "commutator" are synonims, moreover, the last term is considered more correct. Assume I use "switch" instead of.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Akina. Through your and Attie's comments, I'll be able to make the right decision for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as you understand that this is at most an inconvenience, go for it... It has *no* security benefits.

If you don't have access to that subnet (either via a router, or by [multihoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming)) it'll get annoying fast if you need to do any administration...

---

A better (and more secure) solution would be to have the management interface listening on a different VLAN that is specifically for management purposes. Provide access to this VLAN to trusted hosts only - for example by routing.